# script for extracting all gzip files in linux

Tags: linux

All of my files in my linux server converted to gzip files I need a script for extracting all gzip files (*.gz files)

Comment: How did this happen? Surely they didn't just all spontaneously gzip themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ find /path/to/files -name "*.gz" -print0 | xargs -0 gunzip
```

Comment: thank you for your help but can you show me an example of this command

Comment: I want to run this command in cpanel can I use cron jobs to do that?

Comment: The example **is** the answer.

Comment: SSH into your server, then run the command.

Comment: `find /path/to/files -name "*.gz" -exec gunzip {} +` has the same functionality as piping it to xargs, without the extra process or needing -print0/-0 support.

Comment: @astrostl - except for the fact that if you have a large number of files, you'll exceed the allowed number of arguments to gunzip. `xargs` takes care of this gracefully.

Comment: @astrostl: OK, this is an interesting fight. `-exec` requires gunzip (or whatever command) spawning for each file, but `xargs` can use multiple files at once. Which is faster or more scaleable after you hit $some_limit with $certain_environment?

Comment: If all the files on the server have been gzipped, then that presumably includes the find and gunzip binaries. So this command won't work -- and nor will almost any other command.

Comment: @MikeScott - True. Judging by the apparent low skill level of the OP, though, my bet is that "all files" actually means "one directory tree".

Comment: @ErikA: `-exec {} +` doesn't put all arguments in a single invocation: (man page) "the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files."

Comment: @Janne `-exec {} +` works like xargs, with many arguments to a single command.  `-exec ;` invokes the command for each argument.  Semicolon and plus behavior is very different.

Comment: [UsingFind: Actions in bulk: xargs, -print0 and -exec +](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-) from GreyCat's Wiki for reference.